# hide show li sub elements with a back button

Tags: jquery, html, list

I am trying to create a menu where a user can click through and drill down. The user is able to drill back to the parent element with the help of a back element. `li` elements with sub elements are prepended with a `>` so the user will know sub elements are available. The `>` is independent from the `li` parent text. Below is the code that I have come up with so far.

```js
$(function() {
        $("li ul").hide();
        $(".backText").hide();
        //$("body > ul > li").each(function () {
        //    var kids = $(this).children("ul").length;
        //    if (kids > 0) {
        //        $('<span class="">SUB</span>').insertAfter($(this).find('a').first());
        //    }
        //});
        var currentChildLevel;
        var previousLevel;
        var isAChild; //means it belongs to parent li

        $("li ul").hide();
        $("li > a + ul").prev("a").after('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="children"> > </span>');

        $("li a").click(function () {
            console.log($(this).text());
        });
        
        $("span.children").on('click', function() {
            //set parent text
            var parentText = $(this).prev("a").text();
            
            //hide other li
            $("li").hide();

            //show clicked as a back button
            $(".backText").text(parentText).show();

            //show uls under clicked parent
            $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();

            //$(this).parent().show();
            //$(this).siblings('li').show();
            //console.log(parentText);
            //currentChildLevel = $(this).closest("ul");
            //console.log($(this).next('ul'));
            //this exposes ul elements
            //$(this).siblings('ul').first().slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        ul {
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="backText"></div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Green tea</a>
                <ul class="test">
                    <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tea9000</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Green tea</a>
                <ul class="test">
                    <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tea 777</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Green tea</a>
                <ul class="test">
                    <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tea 1122</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Green tea</a>
                <ul class="test">
                    <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I added this line `$(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle();` which should be run after a user clicks `>` and it should expose the sub `uls` but its not working.

Anyone know how to go about it.

Comment: hey, sorry for the delay had some tasks so couldnt get time to attend, i have updated the script to meet your needs so that you can drill down and go back up the rest of fancy things are on you to complete , hope it helps , i have updated the code snippet do copy the javascript section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hide the child `ul` within the parents `li` siblings only using `$(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide();` rather than hiding all the `li` which in result hides the `li` inside the `ul` you are trying to show.

Change this

```
//hide other li
$("li").hide();
```

to this

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('ul').hide();
```

See demo below

```js
$(function() {
  $("li ul").hide();
  $(".backText").hide();

  var currentChildLevel;
  var previousLevel;
  var isAChild; //means it belongs to parent li

  $("li ul").hide();
  $("li > a + ul").prev("a")
    .after('<i class="fas fa-level-down-alt children"></i>')
    .after('<i class="fas fa-level-up-alt parent"></i>');

  $("i.children").on('click', function() {

    //set parent text
    var parentText = $(this).prev("a").text();

    //hide other li
    $(this).parent().siblings().hide();

    //show clicked as a back button
    $(".backText").text(parentText).show();

    //show uls under clicked parent
    $(this).siblings('ul:first').show();

  });

  $("i.parent").on('click', function() {
    var parentUl = $(this).closest('ul');
    var backText = $(this).closest('ul').parent('li').find('a:first').text();
    if (backText == '') {
      //show clicked as a back button
      $(".backText").hide();
    } else {
      //show clicked as a back button
      $(".backText").text(backText);
    }
    parentUl.children().show().find('ul').hide();
  });

});
```

```css
span.children,
span.parent {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 12px;
}

ul {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.children,
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="backText"></div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Tea</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Green tea</a>
        <ul class="test">
          <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tea9000</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Green tea</a>
        <ul class="test">
          <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tea 777</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Green tea</a>
        <ul class="test">
          <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Tea 1122</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Black tea</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Green tea</a>
        <ul class="test">
          <li><a href="#">Black b</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Black c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
</ul>
```

## `EDIT`

I have updated the script above so that you can drill down and go back up the tree and only the current tree is visible when you are drilling down. Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: This is a **`GREAT`** start but I also want to hide the other li and only show the hierachy of the clicked element.

Comment: it is working as you want it to have you tried clicking any other menu item after open children menu of one @mpora

Comment: Its working half way. Look at this website under commodities: https://resourcetrade.earth/data

Comment: that is totally different it hides the whole section and makes visible only one

Comment: Oh ok, that is what I am looking to achieve. Your answer has led me half way to it.

Comment: will hiding the rest of menu items and showing the current hierarchy only work for you? @mpora

Comment: Yes I am definitely looking to hide the whole section and be able to get back to it witch a back button.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Omer Aslam but I ended up going with a library (https://github.com/grubersjoe/slide-menu) I found. I had to modify it around too though.

Comment: ok as you wish @mpora but you can mark the answer as correct as it provides the solution if that is ok with you